# How to make full screen activity when a box is checked

Tags: java, android, fullscreen

I'm trying to make a setting in my app so when the user checks a box than the app goes full screen but every time I run the activity it forces close:

```
CheckBox FullScreen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);

    if (FullScreen.isChecked()) {
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

How can I achieve desired behaviour?
Here are my logcat errors:

```
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491): Process: com.jason.payday, PID: 30491
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jason.payday/com.jason.payday.settings}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2334)
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491):    at com.jason.payday.settings.onCreate(settings.java:42)
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491):    at           android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
08-20 23:09:23.328: E/AndroidRuntime(30491):    
... 11 more
```

Comment: you can do this after setContentView if you want the place this code before setContentView() and this only can be achieved when you go to this activity you cant call windowmanger for full screen on button click

Comment: how can it works  if (FullScreen.isChecked()) ??

Comment: how do i post my logat? im sorry im new. and becuse FullScreen is a checkBox var.

Comment: you say FullScreen is your checkbox variable but as per your code it is a boolean variable and this is the reason of your crash. @jasonflanagan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two questions:

1. How to make an Activity fullscreen?
2. Why is my app crashing with nullpointer?

Here are both

```
CheckBox FullScreen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setcontentview(R.layout.settings);
    // initialize the checkbox, else nullpointer in if-condition (q2)
    FullScreen = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.myFullscreenCheckbox);
    if (FullScreen.isChecked()) {
        // make app fullscreen (q1)
        this.getWindow().setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        );
        setcontentview(R.layout.settings);
    }
}
```

But then again, this code is kinda useless since the checkbox is always initialized either true or false, depending on your xml. You should make use of `SharedPrefernces`, to persist settings and load them once the app starts. Quick tutorial.

Get fullscreen setting:

```
boolean fullscreen = 
    getSharedPreferences("settings", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("fullscreen", false);
```

save fullscreen setting:

```
boolean fullscreen = mycheckbox.isChecked();
getSharedPreferences("settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("fullscreen", fullscreen).commit();
```

Comment: that did it, im vary sorry for the code errors, im still trying to learn, thx you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

call `setContentView(R.layout.settings);`

after

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: still forces close when i do that

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `setcontentview(Your layout);` after

```
   this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Now no crash will appear. Let me know if you still found any issue.
Else I suggest an option for you save the checkbox option in Preferences.

Like http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-android-program-demonstrate-preference-screen/

Comment: if(FullScreen.isChecked()){
     this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
      
     }
    
   setContentView(R.layout.settings);        im useing that and it still closes

Answer (score 0):

when your checkbox state becomes **true** put this code

```
buttonFullscreen
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0,
                        boolean b) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(b)
                    getWindow().setFlags(
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please share the force close logs. Looking at your code, I think force close is not related to Full Screen flag. I suspect it is due to something else. If you are on Ubuntu, you can get force close logs by below command,

```
adb logcat | grep "AndroidRuntime"
```

About the solution, Do not set FullScreen flags in OnCreate.
If you want to do it on button click then set onclicklistener. If you want to do it on CheckBox state change listner then set checkstate change listener. Add below code in the event

```
if (fullScreen == true) {
                    getWindow().addFlags(
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                } else {
                    getWindow().clearFlags(
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                }
```